# Database for Macroinvertebrate Taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy, database, invertebrates

I compiled different data sets of invertebrate occurrences across some countries and now I want to ensure that all the taxonomic information is homogenized and correct. To this end, I am looking for a database which allows me to evaluate my date. Basically, the equivalent to what algaebase.org is for algae.

I know about gbif.org but already found some mistakes in there.

Comment: Have you sent your observations to gbif.org? Sure they would be happy to improve their database...

Comment: No, not yet but thanks for the suggestions I will consider it in the future.

Comment: So, you have the mistakes you found, why not send those now?

Comment: Because I did not keep a record. I just cross-checked algae base with gbif on some species and found different results on what is considered the expected name and what a synonym.